# How spark shuffle works if reading data from multiple MapR locations?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, mapr

I have 2 locations in my MapR cluster, and my spark job is loading data from those 2 endpoints.
One of the endpoints have huge data, and other comparetively less.
Now, when am doing a shuffle operation like a `.reduceByKey` or `.groupByKey` am getting OOM exception:

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$3.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$3.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.allocateNewChunkIfNeeded(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.write(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:75)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flushBufferedData(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:220)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.write(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:173)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:185)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.close(Output.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.close(KryoSerializer.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$blockifyObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1368)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.serializeMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:810)
    at org.apache.spark.ShuffleStatus.serializedMapStatus(MapOutputTracker.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster$MessageLoop.run(MapOutputTracker.scala:397)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"
```

Now, if I copy the data from 1 location to the other and then perform the shuffle operation am not getting any timeout exception.
Why is such a behaviour of spark? As per my understanding, the shuffle operation will happen on the rdd, so irrespective of it reading data from n number of location, it should behave similarly.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Some aspects of the question are pretty confusing.

First, you refer to having data in "2 locations" within a MapR cluster. Do you mean data in two directories? Or do you really mean two locations? Or do you mean you actually have two clusters?

Another confusing point is that you show a stack trace for an out-of-memory problem, but then you talk about timeouts of some kind. Which problem do you actually have?

In general, out of memory exceptions do not depend much on the data source but have a lot to do with over commitment of resources. Overcommitment can be useful if you have lots of tasks that use much less memory or CPU than they might but where you might have a few that use much more. Over committing your resources lets you schedule programs of this kind but can lead to serious problems if multiple big tasks land on the same machine. This can also lead to somewhat random behavior so that if you aren't careful about verifying your theories about what is happening, you can easily jump to incorrect conclusions.

Under YARN, it is common to depend on overcommitment. If you are running on Kubernetes, more precision is common.

Unfortunately, without more specifics / consistency in the question, such generalities are about the best that can be offered.

Comment: Sorry for creating confusion.

Comment: To clarify your above doubts:
1> we are using a single MapR cluster, and reading files from 2 differenct repositories.
2> I wrote it wrong, it OOM only and not timeout exception.

Also, my basic question is does the spark shuffle operation consider it any different if reading the data from single repository or 2 different, because as per my understanding spark shuffle operation works on RDD, and it should not matter how and from where RDD has loaded data.

Having said that, why am I facing a difference in spark behavior in terms of memory consumption?

Comment: Spark does some strange things to decide where temporary files go based on the location of inputs. You might consider checkpointing just before this operation so that things are forced into a single location. There isn't enough information here to figure out what is happening so you need to engage your support team.

Comment: YOu should contact me directly. There are waaay too many variables to solve this without direct interaction.